# Folding list of options

Tags: f#, option-type, fold

Given a list `[Some 1; Some 2; Some 3]` I would like an output `Some 6` . Given a list `[Some 1; None]` should yield `None`.

But I'm finding it a bit more difficult than I had imagined to achieve this in a clean way.

The best I could come up with was this

```
let someNums = [Some 1; Some 2; Some 3]
someNums 
|> List.reduce (fun st v ->
  Option.bind (fun x ->
    Option.map (fun y -> x + y) st) v )
```

Comment: That's a traverse, if you had `sequenceA` it would be `sequenceA [Some 1; Some 2; Some 3] |> Option.map List.sum` look for the code for sequenceA, FsControl has it.

Comment: @Gustavo ;)  you should make this an answer - although I think `FsControl` is just a bit heavy for the *common* F#er ... `pure` Haskell envy if you will ^^

Comment: Yes @Carsten, I agree is too heavy just for this code, that's why I made it as a comment. It's a one liner solution, it could be generalised and further reduced to `sequenceA [Some 1; Some 2; Some 3] |>> sum`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this by defining a `map2` function for option values:

```
let optionMap2 f x y =
    match x, y with
    | (Some x', Some y') -> Some (f x' y')
    | _ -> None
```

This would enable you to write the function you want:

```
let sumSome = List.fold (optionMap2 (+)) (Some 0)
```

Example:

```
> [Some 1; Some 2; Some 3] |> sumSome;;
val it : int option = Some 6
> [Some 1; None; Some 3] |> sumSome;;
val it : int option = None
```

At the moment, the `optionMap2` function isn't available in the F# core library, but [probably will be part of the `Option` module in the future](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/RFCs/FS-1007-additional-Option-module-functions.md).

Comment: this is more or less Functional_S 's answer though - he just called it `lift`

Comment: yeah - I first deleted another answer then editited it and undeleted it

Comment: it's fine to give another answer and I'm sure you did not see it - it's just a bit sad that that you now get the additional rep (I guess because of your higher overall stats) instead of the virtual identical answer that came minutes before ... but that's not about you so don't worry

Comment: I feel like ``optionMap2``follows the F# naming conventions better though, with more pragmatic naming over ambigious naming.

Answer (score 10):

```
let lift op a b =
    match a, b with
    | Some av, Some bv  -> Some(op av bv)
    | _, _ -> None

let plus = lift (+)

[Some 1; Some 2; Some 3]
|> List.reduce plus
// val it : int option = Some 6


[Some 1; None]
|> List.reduce plus
// val it : int option = None
```

with fold

```
[Some 1; None]
|> List.fold plus (Some 0)
// val it : int option = None

[Some 1; Some 2; Some 3]
|> List.fold plus (Some 0)
// val it : int option = Some 6

[Some 1; None; Some 2] 
|> List.fold plus (Some 0)
// val it : int option = None
```

Comment: This only works assuming that the list contains entries that are ``Some<int>``however. Not if you have entries that are ``None`` at which point the reduction should be ``None``.

Comment: ok, that is an additional specification ;-) You don't told what you exactly want, you gave only one sample case.

Comment: That kills my answer, so try to I delete it.

Comment: The use of `List.reduce` means that it's going to crash if supplied with an empty list (`[]`). Consider using `List.fold` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an naive implementation of the `sequence` Gustavo talked about:

```
let rec sequence = 
   function 
   | [] -> Some [] 
   | (Some o :: os) -> 
      sequence os 
      |> Option.map (fun os' -> o::os') 
   | _ -> None
```

(please note that this is not tail-recursive and not optimized at all so you should transform it if you gonna need it for large lists)

Which would work just as Gustavo told you:

```
> sequence [Some 1; Some 2; Some 2] |> Option.map List.sum;;
val it : int option = Some 5

> sequence [Some 1; None; Some 2] |> Option.map List.sum;;
val it : int option = None
```